# Disordered Cryptic Orders

Tags: story, cryptic-clues

**... two targets  ...  the 3 A's of war  ...  dressed in  ... your mission is
... we must prevent ...**

If the first message wasn't cryptic enough, the rest wasn't much clearer.  What we *do* know is that the keywords we need are the answers to 10 cryptic clues.  Unfortunately, the messaging was jumbled en route. We need you to combine these beginnings, middles and ends to form 10 viable cryptic clues. If you do that, the answers will provide the intel we need.

> What are the targets? What are the 3 A's of war?  What must we do, and what are we stopping?

Good luck!

| Beginnings | Middles | Ends |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Some planes rally | missing one | I guess (8) |
| Peace comes | with nothing in | the arms? (9) |
| Battle outfit held | after unfinished request | from a farm (12) |
| Return cooler | in a | Southern country (9) |
| Shot when hostile nation | is not | to depot (7) |
| Silver to lead | in by | moving trap (7) |
| A fraction taken | back | losing Swiss capital (10) |
| Treading dangerously | is inside | Spanish country (6) |
| A blood-vessel disease | in the fat | for disaster (8) |
| Potato Merlin mashed | is mum after | honest procedure (9) |

Answer (score 10, accepted):

(I'll use the usual notation to explain the solutions to the cryptic clues: `*` for anagrams, `_..._` for hidden words, `X_` for first letter selection, `<` for reversal.)

**What are the targets?**

> Return cooler with nothing in Spanish country (6)  -- **`CA<+NADA`**
>  Silver to lead in a Southern country (9) -- **`ARGENT+IN+A`**

**What are the three A's of war?**

> Some planes rally back to depot (7) -- **`_ARSENAL_<`**
>  Shot when hostile nation is mum after losing Swiss capital (10) -- **`AMMUNITION(-s)*`**
>  A blood-vessel disease is inside the arms? (9) -- **`ART(ILL)ERY`**

**What are we dressed in?**

> Battle outfit held in the fat I guess (8) - **`_FATIGUES_`** (a word meaning "combat uniforms")

**What must we do?**

> A fraction taken in by honest procedure (9) -- **`OPE(RATIO)N`**
>  Treading dangerously missing one moving trap (7) -- **`DRAGNET(-i)*`**

**What are we stopping?**

> Potato Merlin mashed is not from a farm (12) -- **`METROPOLITAN*`**
>  Peace comes after unfinished request for disaster (8) -- **`CAL(-l)+AMITY`**

Comment: Add an S to rot13(SNGVTHR) - you need 8 letters - and that's what you're 'dressed in'! Also, maybe see [this](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operation_Dragnet)? You can probably also combine rot13(ZRGEBCBYVGNA PNYNZVGL) into one phrase as what you're trying to prevent :) +1

Comment: With @Stiv 's minor corrections this is 100% correct.  Nice work!!

Answer (score 0):

Partial (One Clue)

> Potato Merlin mashed + is not + from a farm (12) = *METROPOLITAN (def = not from a farm)

Comment: Forgot to mention this earlier, but: I downvoted this answer because a single clue doesn't seem like enough to justify a partial answer. See [this meta post](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6705/partial-answers-and-list-of-clues-puzzles) for more thoughts on the subject.